# How to merge a date range in django templates/views

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I would like to know how to merge months and years when displaying a date in a Django template.

From this:

```
Oct. 12, 2012 - Oct. 20, 2012
```

To this:

```
Oct. 12-20, 2012
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work. It makes sure that the month and year are the same, in which case outputs string like `Oct. 12-20, 2012`. If not, then it outputs `Oct. 12, 2012 - Oct. 22, 2013`.

```
{% if date1|date:"nY" == date2|date:"nY" %} {# same month and day #}
    {{ date1|date:"N j" }}-{{ date2|date:"j, Y" }}
{% else %}
    {{ date1|date:"N j, Y" }} - {{ date2|date:"N j, Y" }}
{% endif %}
```

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#date) is a full reference for Django `date` template filter.